How to type hint a property on $this in php?
Assume that in a template.phtml, there is a property someInstance of the class SomeClass defined on $this.
So in the file, one has access to:
$this->someInstance

yet the developer has no immediate clue what type $this->someInstance is.
I know I could typehint on the fly:
<?php

class SomeClass {
    public int $foo;
    public string $bar;
}


$someInstance = $this->someInstance;
/**
 * @var SomeClass $someInstance
 */
$someInstance-> // I have autocompletion here


Yet is there a way to provide a phpdoc for $this->someInstance directly without going through an extra local variable?
My goal is to add code-documentation to existing files without adding to much refactoring noise.
I tried:
/**
 * @var SomeClass $this->someInstance
 */

and:
/**
 * @var SomeClass $this::someInstance
 */

yet that did not work.

$this is only available in a class-object context.. you can't use it from global scope, like you do in your example.

As a workaround you may be able to add classes as documentation for your views, e.g. for your template.phtml, add:
class TemplateView {
    public SomeClass $someInstance;
}

And then you could typehint $this:
/**
 * @var TemplateView $this
 */
$this-> // you have autocomplete here




Rather than a "workaround", I'd say this is "normal code" - how and why are you creating an object with a known structure without declaring a class in the first place?

@IMSoP I would like to ask that very question to the developers who made the codebase as it is. I am just trying to find a way to deal with it.

Haha, that's a very reasonable answer, sometimes you just have to work with what you've got! :)
